# htaccess forward all users to a single file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Good day,

I am using a framework that uses a .htaccess file to forward all requests to a sub file **core/index.php**

I used the following .htaccess file code :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine           on
    RewriteRule             ^$    core/    [L]

    # If the request is not for a valid directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # If the request is not for a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule    (.*) core/$1    [L]
 </IfModule>
```

This worked great I thought until I noticed that the pages got loaded multiple times.
And this is what I want to prevent.

So I had a little look at this forum.
And I found a solution that the space between **(.*)** and **core** could be the reason.

Hence I removed it.

And to my delight the multiple db inserts stopped.
However now I have found that my requests do not get forwarded correctly.
Only the main request *(www.myapplication.com/)* gets forwarded correctly (index.php)

Whenever I am adding something like : *(www.myapplication.com/admin)* he bugs out and cannot find the page.

I hope anyone could tell me what to modify in this code :

```
RewriteEngine           on
RewriteRule             ^$    core/    [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    (.*) core/$1    [L]
```

Thanks in advance!!

I also note that whenever I change the **(.*) core/$1 [L]*** line to **(.)core/$1 [L]** that not only my (sub)pages stopped working but for the index.php the load times of my index.php file where split in half.
Hence my page truly gets reloaded multiple times.

**Edit**
As pointed out by a question below the system also uses a .htaccess file inside the /core directory.

This file has the following contents

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]


    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
        ErrorDocument 404 index.php
    </IfModule>
```

> **Edit**
>
> I think it would come handy to make a small summary. If requested for a file or path I want the server to check if it is
>   available on the server.
>       www.myapplication.com/flower.jpeg and the server can find it it should display the flower.jpeg file.
>       If the server CAN NOT find the flower.jpeg file I want the server to forward the request to /core/index.php?url=flower.jpeg
>
> ```
> I am using two .htaccess files
> in the **public directory** (main directory)
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>     RewriteEngine           on
>     RewriteRule             ^$    core/    [L]
>
>     # If the request is not for a valid directory
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>     # If the request is not for a valid file
>     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>     RewriteRule (.*) core/$1    [L]
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core/
>  </IfModule>
> ```
>
> Second file in the core directory
>   **core/**
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> # Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
>
>
> </IfModule>
> <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
>   ErrorDocument 404 index.php
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> *The issue: my pages are in a loop hence the page index.php get's executed with every server request. E.G. 10 images on a page means 10
>   requests extra. Same for js and CSS files.*

edit:

---

> **Solved!!!**
>
> This is the solution!!
>       DirectoryIndex core/index.php
>
> ```
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine on
>
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
>  </IfModule>
> ```

Comment: Search for "rewrite loop" with your favourite search engine.

Comment: YES I KNOW!!! I fixed it by removing the space. But that broke the rest.. Hence I am a little bit lost to make it stop looping and stay working. I just cannot get to work out a correct syntax.

Comment: You have to exclude the target file from redirection, thats the point.

Comment: RewriteRule    (.*)<HERE WHAS A SPACE>core/$1    [L]
but this space is needed to keep it working. At least the way it is now..

Comment: RewriteRule requires two parameters to work, so it does not function anymore if the space is removed.

Comment: Yes it has. Good point I add it to the topic

Comment: If you request for something like domain.tld/notexist that will get reqritten to domain.tld/core/notexist. Is that what you intend? Because most likely the file will not be found in the core folder as well. `RewriteRule    (.*) core/$1    [L]` takes the whole URI and prepends it with core/. Shouldnt that be `RewriteRule    (.*) core/index.php    [L]`?

Comment: @anubhava because I run a MySQL query and I notice it gets executed a random number of times at a single page load.

For being sure that I did not make any errors and included the file twice I created a small PDO insert test function and ran it at first lines of the index.php. And even then it got executed ten or twenty times.

Comment: But to write to the database, a script has to be executed actually? So the rewrites must have stopped. Do you have forwards inside that script?

Comment: I found out (thanks to the access log) that the number of iterations depend on the number of requests made to the server. If I have ten .js files and five images the total number of inserts is 16. Hence the problem is there where the rewrite for the existing files takes place. It doesn't stop there.

Comment: @anubhava  `#ErrorDocument 404 index.php` But no luck. Also removing it did not help.

Comment: Maybe it would make sense to move this to chat. Anyways, I am still waiting for an answer to my question from above starting with "If you request for something like domain.tld/notexist" (replace URI with path there)

Comment: @syck
You mean to go to ? (never done that) https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

About your question. I am sorry I have overlooked this question.
Thats correct. I want all requests that do not end up in a file found to be forwarded to the core/index.php?url=$1

Comment: Nope, there should be a possibility to convert a long list of comments into a question-specific chat by the OP. But I am not really experienced at the questioning side.

Comment: okay, but with `$1` you end up having the original request path only to be prepended by `core/`. What about `RewriteRule    (.*) core/index.php?url=$1    [L]`?

Comment: @syck `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine           on
    RewriteRule             ^$    core/    [L]

    # If the request is not for a valid directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # If the request is not for a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule    (.*) core/index.php?url=$1    [L]
 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core/
 </IfModule>`
Renders the second .htaccess file needless but it does not resolve the issue.

Hmm.. little cluttered answer..
Adding `index.php?url=$1 ` makes the second .htaccess file not needed.

Comment: Having a RewriteCond after the last RewriteRule does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found a solution. The working code is :
>
> ```
> DirectoryIndex core/index.php
>
> <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
>   RewriteEngine on
>
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ core/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
>  </IfModule>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core/
```

to the RewriteCond block to prevent redirection **from** the target **to** the target.

It would be better if your target would be more specific, for example if you could specify `/core/` instead of `core/` (do you have a core subfolder in every folder?). Also, you will have to exclude image folders.

Comment: I added this And I now have 

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) core/$1    [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !core/

But it still loops..
I want the system to check if the file requested exists. E.g. www.myapplication.com/flower.jpeg and if so display it. But if NOT forward all requests to /core/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `/core/.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 404 default
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```